# How could you increase the maximum recursion depth in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, stack-overflow

Interesting topic of recursion and stack overflow in class today and I wondered if there is any way of increasing the maximum recursion depth in Python? Wrote a quick function for finding the factorial of n using recursion:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

It can cope with factorial(994) but not factorial(995). The error given is:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Obviously a higher factorial can be found iteratively but, for the sake of argument and intrigue, can the maximum recursion depth be increased?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit

Comment: Note that the standard way of avoiding too much recursion here is to use memoization.

Comment: Nope, there is no hate in here. We all are here to help others. Closing as a dupe doesn't mean that we *hate* you. All the best in future.

Comment: If implementing factorial program using recursion is necessary. You can implement it in following manner which is able to find factorial without any limit using python.    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A0z9eyXD5mNIAZRotX5RM2QAu9bbZqHa/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import sys

iMaxStackSize = 5000
sys.setrecursionlimit(iMaxStackSize)
```